# Asp net core mvc reading chip data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have project in Asp.net core (3.1) MVC and want to read chip data. For example: Somebody will come to store. They will put their chip on chip reader and then they could access their account... Basically I want this: They will see page asking for chip -> They will chip on website -> I will read chip data (in my case string) and send it to server. I dont know if this is more JavaScript/JQuery question or c#... I dont know where to start. Some idea/library/documentation? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What "chip"?  If you're talking about interfacing with some sort of hardware then presumably the manufacturer of that hardware has documentation and perhaps an API?

Comment: Yes I am talking about hardware (sorry, forgot to write). Problem is that manufacturer has only c# implement but I dont know how to get that data on server. So I know how to read that data but dont know how to send it to server.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what architecture you're trying to build.  You are requiring that the client have a specific piece of hardware, but are unable to install any software on the client?  Why can't you use a C# application on the client?  Why does this have to be done from within a web browser?

Comment: Because there is a lot (really lot) of working pieces of hardware but I cant install my app on all of them, so I need to do it in Asp net core mvc. I know its weird but its maybe only option I have at this point. But I would welcome any idea!

Comment: Any way you look at it, your users are going to have to install something.  I highly doubt that a sandboxed in-browser environment is going to have direct access to hardware.  So even then you'll still need them to install some sort of browser plugin.  You might contact the manufacturer to see if they have any SDK other than C#, if you're against using .NET applications on the clients.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help!